# Problems with PublicPacletInstall

Tags: packages

I tried to install the following package:

```
    << https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/Install.wl
    PublicPacletInstall["EasyIDE"]
```

The output:

[image]

Can anyone guide me on this error?

In advance, I appreciate your suggestions or solutions.

Comment: As the person who wrote that package and the distribution mechanism, WRI has changed the underlying infrastructure for paclets and I don't develop in Mathematica anymore so I haven't been able to update the paclet server to use the new stuff

Comment: I appreciate that you responded so quickly. Greetings.